# Wordpress async_upload.php 500 Error when Uploading larger files with slow internet connection and latency

Tags: php, wordpress, asynchronous, file-upload, upload

my page runs on a local corporate network on a Windows 2016 server running IIS 10. PHP 7.1 WordPress 5.3

The page is used as a video platform. Videos up to 2GB can be uploaded. From our locations on the same network (upload speed 25-50Mbps) the upload works without any problems. The corresponding parameters in IIS, php.ini and wp-config.php are set correctly. The timeouts on the server and the proxies are set to 2 hrs.

The problem is:

Uploads >300MB will not complete from other locations over WAN. The connection corresponds to approx. 4Mbps uploadspeed with 130ms latency. If I simulate the upload in Chrome with these settings, I will end up with a 500 error of async-upload.php. How can I optimize the page for slow connections and latency?

I am grateful for hints!

Chrome Network Log:

Request URL: https://XXX.intra.net/wp-admin/async-upload.php

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Remote Address: 53.26.9.187:3128

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Connection: close

Content-Length: 1208

Content-Type: text/html

Date: Mon, 02 Dec 2019 13:40:45 GMT

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

X-Powered-By: XXX

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 518192654

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundaryBYhwvYy8edwoTGJh

Cookie: wordpress_sec_8e85a50d55023e68686338106663e49d=mwerbro%7C1575444406%7CmsjSnLM6HQzCeaOxjCP7aKQvqApaGGc45mHp5xiJusy%7C1632275c6b5a9f9e15fbbac0896441e90e82a263ad537b7f64fa39488e5cc72b; vchideactivationmsg_vc11=6.0.5; catAccCookies=1; wp-settings-time-134=1575035781; wp-settings-134=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dhtml%26edit_element_vcUIPanelWidth%3D649%26edit_element_vcUIPanelLeft%3D923px%26edit_element_vcUIPanelTop%3D74px%26posts_list_mode%3Dlist; wordpress_logged_in_8e85a50d55023e68686338106663e49d=mwerbro%7C1575444406%7CmsjSnLM6HQzCeaOxjCP7aKQvqApaGGc45mHp5xiJusy%7Cecc5ac52a0f081c9ec834ca0a2036b2bf44482f02a5f20e1184f7fa585053bc3; wp-wpml_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e=de; _pk_ref.275.97ea=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1575288534%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.intra.corpintra.net%2Finbox%22%5D; _pk_ses.275.97ea=1; wp-wpml_current_language=de; _pk_id.275.97ea=4c61b23bd9343dc7.1571816982.119.1575293156.1575288534.; ADRUM=s=1575293617793&r=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.intra.corpintra.net%2Flogin.jspa%3F-72025792

Host: XXX.intra.net

Origin: https://XXX.intra.net

Referer: https://XXX.intra.net/wp-admin/media-new.php

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36

name: C0008.MP4

post_id: 0

_wpnonce: 523ff9aa48

type:

tab:

short: 1

async-upload: (binary)

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: In fact, there was still a timeout for fastCGI not set correctly. It works now.